# Tracking performance with code

Tags: angularjs

I am curious about AngularJS performance of the digest cycle.  I would like to track how much total time is spent in the digest cycle on all browsers.  So Batarang does not help me.  Is there some event or some hook that gets triggered on the start of the digest cycle and after the digest cycle is completed?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the browser's developer tools?

In Chrome, open console, go to *Profiles* -> *Collect JS CPU profile* -> Run (the circle in corner). Then in result you can see each function, ie. $digest, $apply ...

Similar in Firefox, open console, go to *Profiler* and hit the clock icon in corner

Comment: That is fine, but is there a programmtic way of doing it, so I can repeat the test easily?

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [angular-performance](https://github.com/Linkurious/angular-performance) Chrome extension, it provides monitoring for watchers, digest timing, digest rate and sync/async timing of service function execution.

Disclamer: I am the author of the extension